# How to determine a 90 degree turn on Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-4

I have the following case to determine the user's turn 90 degrees or more with only using Apple Watch.

I wanted to do this with `CLLocationManager` and `startUpdatingHeading`, but [Heading](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620558-startupdatingheading) does not support watchOS. At the moment I'm at a dead end, and I do not know the solutions to this problem. Are there any disputes to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the CLLocation portion that supplies Course.  This is available on Watch.  The Heading information is derived from the internal phone compass and I’m not sure that is currently supported on the Watch. (Docs don’t show it is.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no compass in the Apple Watch if you check the spec. Let's why you don't see a compass app.

You have to use CoreMotion and get the gyroscope data. You probably also have to do some math to calculate the degree.

http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/accelerometer-gyro